# SQL Selecting average of rating from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I have two tables: Anime_List and Anime_Reviews.

Anime_List table has a 'Rating' field that grabs the average rating from Anime_Reviews. However, some ratings (rows) don't exist in Anime_Reviews and so my current query only returns titles that have a average rating.

```
SELECT Anime_List.AnimeID, Anime_List.Name, Anime_List.AnimeImage, Anime_List.Synopsis, Anime_List.Type, Anime_List.Episodes, Anime_List.Genres, AVG(Anime_Reviews.Rating) 
FROM Anime_List INNER JOIN Anime_Reviews ON Anime_List.AnimeID = Anime_Reviews.AnimeID
GROUP BY Anime_List.AnimeID, Anime_List.Name, Anime_List.AnimeImage, Anime_List.Synopsis, Anime_List.Type, Anime_List.Episodes, Anime_List.Genres
```

How do I return the value of 0.0 if there are no ratings (rows) in Anime_Reviews for each title listed in Anime_List?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A version using a subquery

```
SELECT l.AnimeID, 
       l.Name, 
       l.AnimeImage, 
       l.Synopsis, 
       l.Type, 
       l.Episodes, 
       l.Genres, 
       (SELECT ISNULL(AVG(Rating), 0) Rating
          FROM Anime_Reviews 
         WHERE AnimeID = l.AnimeID)
  FROM Anime_List l
```

Comment: This isn't the solution I wanted as it returns 2 columns of rating (because of that l.*), but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yep, it works now. I like using a subquery is easier/cleaner than using COALESCE (in my case).

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
  l.AnimeID, 
  l.Name, 
  l.AnimeImage, 
  l.Synopsis, 
  l.Type, 
  l.Episodes, 
  l.Genres, 
  COALESCE(AVG(r.Rating), 0) AS Rating 
FROM Anime_List AS l
LEFT JOIN Anime_Reviews AS r ON l.AnimeID = r.AnimeID
GROUP BY l.AnimeID, 
         l.Name, 
         l.AnimeImage, 
         l.Synopsis, 
         l.Type, 
         l.Episodes, 
         l.Genres;
```

For more information about the different types of SQL `JOIN` see this article please:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).